# Is COM+ component exposing ADODB supported on 2012 64bit windows server?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, 64-bit, windows-server-2012, com+

we're migrating certain COM+ components from VB6.0 to C#.Net. I'm facing some challenges regarding the conversion of code (rewriting), one thing is this particular COM+ component will be consumed by multiple classic asp applications, these applications either pass ADODB Recordset as input parameter and also accept it as an output parameter. after developing a piece of code and testing it locally on 32 bit machine I'm able to build the connectionstring and also pass and accept Recordset. but when I migrate to code to windows 2012 R2 64 bit server. I see error when I try to create the object of the DLL.

So my question is it possible to use Recordset and expose it through COM+ on 64 bit machine?

Comment: I don't see why it inherently wouldn't work. What is this "error" and what is meant by "create the object"?

Comment: with this DLL we're supposed to expose 3 modules and we we instantiate the object we get error.                            Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 80004005'

Server.CreateObject Failed

Comment: You could try setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True in the Advanced Settings of the Application Pool associated with you web site.

Comment: scdudel, I have done that, building tlb,dll and deployed it as a component service on server with proper access to the user. I read somewhere in forum that especially ADODB will not be supported on 64 bit environment so just getting clarified

Comment: Mahesh, schudel give you right answer: enabling 32-bit application setting will help. We are using old 32-bit COM on 2008R2 and 2012, it's using ADODB - all works fine. Try view all securities for your COM component: "standart" file permissions and in "component services" launch and active permissions.